# How can I set the Eclipse JS to edit a file as CSS

Tags: css, eclipse, editor, less

I use the lesscss, it's works fine, but the Eclipse editor doesn't highlight the words, and the Zen Coding doesn't recognize that a css file. How can I open the .less file as a .css file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577637/less-css-support-for-eclipse-pdt

Comment: No, it's not a working plugin... and I would need only a setting, but thank you!

Comment: Surely you'll need a plugin of some kind to make Eclipse do syntax highlighting for `.less` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: in the general menu -> content types option I can add a file association to the css content type.

Comment: Thank You,We can add any type of file ,just need to mention as *.filetype  (*.less  or *.scss)